# Automatically print every email message from a certain sender in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I would like to be able to set up Gmail so that it prints an email as soon as the email registers in the account inbox. I am interested in printing all emails from a certain sender. I am open to using other tools like Thunderbird if this simplifies the job. But the ideal solution would be something right in Gmail that can be configured and left alone.

Is there any simple way to do this with Gmail?

Comment: There's no way to do this with just Gmail. You'll need at least one third-party tool.

Comment: Any recommendations?

Comment: Maybe the [HP Print](https://ifttt.com/hp) channel on IFTTT.

Comment: Any open source options?

Comment: If that's what you're after try asking on [softwarerecs.se].